# PHP page stops loading halfway through - Doesn't finish code

Tags: php, gmail-api

I have a web application where I look through all mails in the inbox of my Gmail-account and search for specific strings to pick out different emails.

On this app I can set a limit on how many emails to search. If I set this limit to "200" or lower it works just fine most of the times.
But if i increase the limit to 400 and up that, 99% of the times, the application/page stops loading. And the code doesn't finish.

I have enabled so PHP shows error messages via the host website and also via this code at the begining of each php page:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
?>
```

However, when the page stops loading, no error messages is displayed. (And it does display on other errors)

This is the code I'm using, together with Gmail API.

```
<?php
//Authentication with Gmail API happens here
$gmail = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);
$number_of_emails_to_fetch = 500; 
$list = $gmail->users_messages->listUsersMessages('me', ['maxResults' => $number_of_emails_to_fetch]);


$filename = "unsubscribe-show-all.php";
$sql_table_name = create_table();
$connection = open_connection();
while ($list->getMessages() != null) {

    foreach ($list->getMessages() as $mlist) {

        $message_id = $mlist->id;
        $optParamsGet2['format'] = 'full';
        $single_message = $gmail->users_messages->get('me', $message_id, $optParamsGet2);
        $payload = $single_message->getPayload();
        $parts = $payload->getParts();
        // With no attachment, the payload might be directly in the body, encoded.
        $body = $payload->getBody();
        $FOUND_BODY = FALSE;
        // If we didn't find a body, let's look for the parts
        if(!$FOUND_BODY) {
            foreach ($parts  as $part) {
                if($part['parts'] && !$FOUND_BODY) {
                    foreach ($part['parts'] as $p) {
                        if($p['parts'] && count($p['parts']) > 0){
                            foreach ($p['parts'] as $y) {
                                if(($y['mimeType'] === 'text/html') && $y['body']) {
                                    $FOUND_BODY = decodeBody($y['body']->data);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        } else if(($p['mimeType'] === 'text/html') && $p['body']) {
                            $FOUND_BODY = decodeBody($p['body']->data);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if($FOUND_BODY) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
       
        // If we didn't find the body in the last parts, 
        // let's loop for the first parts (text-html only)
        if(!$FOUND_BODY) {
            foreach ($parts  as $part) {
                if($part['body'] && $part['mimeType'] === 'text/html') {
                    $FOUND_BODY = decodeBody($part['body']->data);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        // With no attachment, the payload might be directly in the body, encoded.
        if(!$FOUND_BODY) {
            $FOUND_BODY = decodeBody($body['data']);
        }
        if(!$FOUND_BODY) {
            $FOUND_BODY = '(No message)';
        }
}
?>
```

After this code I have more code that handles inserting different links into databases followed by a redirection.
However, i tried removing that code and only running the code above + the redirection, but the page still stops loading, so I figure it has something to do with this snippet.

Any advice on where to read, or hints on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The last two if statements are identical, is this intentional?

Comment: The code you have shown appears to contain a parse error. You can not set the error reporting level _inline_ using `error_reporting()`/`ini_set()`, if you have errors that prevent your _whole_ code from executing in the first place.

Comment: Okay, so I didn't see this before. But apparently, when I check the network, it throws an "503 Service Unavailable" error. I guess the server is overloaded(?).
Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @Epodax Yes, it's intentional. I just use the same variable as a string for the body, and string for the message to check if something was found.